# MSBuild SonarQube runner skipping auto-generated files?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have set up a local SonarQube 5.1.1 server. I have also installed the C# plugin (version 4.1), as well as the MSBuild runner (version 1.0). I then performed two separate runs on the .NET codebase for the project I am currently working on:

1. Using sonar-runner and the C# plugin
2. Using the MSBuild runner

Both runs were made through the CLI. However, the runs yielded very different results. Here is an example: In the first run SonarQube calculated the number of code lines to be roughly 956 000, while in the second run it was calculated to be "only" about 434 000. I then did some digging, and it seems like the latter skips some auto-generated files. These files/classes were generated by an old, internally developed ORM tool.

I thought that unless specified otherwise - by using include/exclude patterns - the MSBuild SonarQube runner would analyse **every** single .cs file in a given project, but apparently that is not the case.

Has anyone experienced the same "problem", and does anyone know what kind of auto-generated files that will be automatically excluded from an analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some information in the [Sonar .NET documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md#excluding-artefacts-from-analysis), which states, among other things, states that:

"*Certain types of project will automatically be excluded from analysis. For example, Microsoft Fakes generates additional projects during build. These auto-generated projects will not be analysed.*"

and

"*Files that are generated by custom tools within Visual Studio are automatically excluded from analysis, such as the xxx.Designer.cs file generated from a .resx file:*"

I assume that our internal ORM tool falls into the latter category. Thus, that explains why those files are being excluded from the analysis.

Comment: And by the way, the goal is to go even further by automatically excluding source code annotated with [GeneratedCode], [CompilerGenerated], ... attributes : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vs/issues/164

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for the information, @Freddy - SonarSource Team.