# Sonarqube TFS build Ignore issues on files

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm using Sonarqube 5.1.2 with MSBuild Sonarqube runner 1.0. I have set up build in TFS that triggers the sonarqube runner and it works fine. Sourcecode is C#, Javascript and CSS.

I want to ignore auto generated files, so I have tried to enter this regex
`.*<auto-generated>.*` in the Ignore Issues on Files section in Sonarqube, but this causes the sonarqube runner to hang on the analyze phase forever. 
If I remove the regex, the build runs fine. 
Anyone else have experienced this?

Comment: I think I actually found the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962814/msbuild-sonarqube-runner-skipping-auto-generated-files

Answer (score 0):

Paths are relative to the project base directory.
only below Wildcards can be used while specifying exclusion list

```
*   Match zero or more characters
**  Match zero or more directories
?   Match a single character
```

let's say if your autogenerated files and other files are under src folders. You can ignore using this line `**/src/*autogeneated*`
You can follow this [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns) for more details

Comment: Ok, but I thought this only applied when I want to exclude based on the filename itself.  I want to use the "Ignore Issues on Files" and exclude based on content in the file.  The documentation says:  You can ignore all issues on files that contain a block of code matching a given regular expression.
Example: Ignore all issues on files containing @javax.annotation.Generated: